# Custom UIButton subclass

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I'm trying my own custom UIButton. I subclassed the UIButton class and tried to add some functions this is my code:

```
import UIKit


class CustomButton: UIButton {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
        setGradientBackground()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    private func setup() {
        layer.cornerRadius = 8
    }

    private func setGradientBackground() {

        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.frame = bounds
        gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.yellow.cgColor, UIColor.blue.cgColor]
        gradientLayer.locations = [0.0, 1.0]
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)

        layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
    }
}
```

I linked it to my IBOutlet :

```
@IBOutlet weak var myButton: CustomButton!
```

And nothing apply !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're adding the button in a storyboard, the initialiser that's called is `init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)`, not `init(frame: CGRect)`, so you need to add…

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    setup()
    setGradientBackground()
}
```

Comment: Try putting a breakpoint in the init method to see if it's called. What happens?

Comment: Sorry It wasn't linked on the storyboard!
 your solution work .. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Use `func awakeFromNib()` :

```
class CustomButton: UIButton {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        setup()
        setGradientBackground()
    }

    private func setup() {
        layer.cornerRadius = 8
    }

    private func setGradientBackground() {

        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.frame = bounds
        gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.yellow.cgColor, UIColor.blue.cgColor]
        gradientLayer.locations = [0.0, 1.0]
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)

        layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
    }
}
```